# Хеширование методом цепочек

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, c++11

При хешировании с цепочками списки элементов с данным хеш-значением будут упорядоченными. Как этот подход повлияет на стоимость успешного поиска, поиска отсутствующего элемента, добавление, удаление?

Comment: Что такое "хеширование с цепочками" и почему списки будут упорядоченными?

Comment: смысль хеширования в том,  что поиск проводится по хэш значению. Порядок тут непричем

Comment: Звучит как вопрос экзамене/собеседовании так-то

Answer (score 0):

Согласно статье на вики:

> [Метод цепочек](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA)
>
> Разрешение коллизий при помощи цепочек.
> Каждая ячейка массива H является указателем на связный список (цепочку) пар ключ->значение, соответствующих одному и тому же хеш-значению ключа. Коллизии просто приводят к >тому, что появляются цепочки длиной более одного элемента.
>
> Операции поиска или удаления элемента требуют просмотра всех элементов соответствующей ему цепочки, чтобы найти в ней элемент с заданным ключом. Для добавления элемента нужно добавить элемент в конец или начало соответствующего списка и в случае, если коэффициент заполнения станет слишком велик, увеличить размер массива H и перестроить таблицу.
>
> При предположении, что каждый элемент может попасть в любую позицию таблицы H с равной вероятностью и независимо от того, куда попал любой другой элемент, среднее время работы операции поиска элемента составляет Θ(1 + α), где α — коэффициент заполнения таблицы.